# Fundamental group of $\Bbb R^3$ minus a plane passing through the origin.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have solved a problem from Hatcher's book which can be found here
[Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ \ finite number of lines passing through origin.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247910/fundamental-group-of-mathbbr3-finite-number-of-lines-passing-through-ori)

So, motivated by this problem, I was thinking about problem like computation of fundamental group of
$\Bbb R^3-\{ax+by+cz=0\}$
And generalization of this problem as like I mentioned above.

Can you please give me any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you fix a base point you get one of the two connected components which is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence is trivial.

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ minus a plane is just two disjoint open half-spaces,  both contractible.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ah yes, you're right. I'm not thinking straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb R^3 \setminus P$ where $P$ is a plane is just a disjoint sum of two copies of $\Bbb R^3$. If $p$ is the base point for the fundamental group, it's in one of these copies so the fundamental group is just the one for that copy (as a loop only lies inside that copy for connectedness reasons) and thus trival (as the space is contractible), i.e. $\{0\}$.